# Can two polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ have just one factor in common?

Tags: field-theory

Let $p(x),q(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$. **EDIT: $\mathbb{F}$ is a field of $0$ characteristic.**

Let us suppose there is an element $b\notin \mathbb{F}$ such that $p(b)=q(b)=0$. Then, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ both have the factor $(x-b)$ in $\mathbb{F}[b,x]$.

My question is can $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, both of which belong to $\mathbb{F}[x]$, have only one common factor $(x-b)$ in $\mathbb{F}[b,x]$ and no other?

***Motivation behind the question***: Let me take you step by step.

1. If $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$, and $f(x)=g(x).h(x)$, where if $g(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$, then $h(x)$ also has to $\in \mathbb{F}[x]$. This is because if $h(x)$ contains coefficients from outside of $\mathbb{F}$, then, considering the coefficients of $g(x)$ are from $\mathbb{F}$, the coefficients of $g(x).h(x)$ wouldn't be from $\mathbb{F}$.
2. Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ such that it has a root $b\notin\mathbb{F}$. Then, $f(x)=g(x).h(x)$ such that $g(x),h(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$, and $g(b)=0$. Obviously, $deg(g(x))\geq 2$, as if it is $1$, then it will be the linear factor $(x-b)$, which is not there in $\mathbb{F}[x]$.
3. Let us factorise $g(x)$ from point $(2)$ in $\mathbb{F}[b,x]$. $(x-b)$ is one factor. Let the other factor be $q(x)$. Then $q(x)\in \mathbb{F}[b,x]$, but $q(x)\notin \mathbb{F}[x]$ (from point $(2)$).
4. Now let us come back to the original question. If $p(x),q(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$ have a common root $b\notin F$, then $p(x)$ will factorise in the form $(x-b)t(x)f(x)$, where $t(x)\in \mathbb{F}[b,x]$ such that $(x-b).t(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$, and $q(x)$ will factorise in the form $(x-b)s(x)g(x)$ such that $s(x)\in\mathbb{F}[b,x]$ such that $(x-b)s(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$. It is clear that $t(x), s(x)\notin \mathbb{F}[x]$. Obviously$f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{F}[x]$. $t(x)\neq s(x)$, as otherwise $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ won't have just $(x-b)$ in common. Also $f(x)\neq g(x)$.
5. Clearly, carrying forward from point $(4)$, $(x-b)t(x)$ and $(x-b)s(x)$ will form **distinct** irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, with no common factors. Hence, as $f(x)\neq g(x)$, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ will not have any common factors in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, but will have the common factor $(x-b)$ in $\mathbb{F}[b,x]$. Isn't this a contradiction of the theorem that if two polynomials have a common factor in a field extension $\mathbb{K}$, then they have to have a common factor in the original field $F$, where  $\mathbb{F}\subset\mathbb{K}$?

The only way out of this contradiction that I can see is if $(x-b)t(x)$ can be factored into $r(x)e(x)$, and $(x-b)s(x)$ into $r(x)u(x)$, where $r(x), e(x)$ and $u(x)\in \mathbb{F}[x]$. $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ will then have the common factor $r(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$. I want to know if this is always possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $b$ divides both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. And that one can't be linear, as $b \not\in \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Thanks! However, Herstein has the following line on Pg 194 as part of Theorem $5.p$ in the chapter "Fields"(Second edition):
_Thus $(x-b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ over some extension of $\mathbb{K}$._

Comment: The greatest common divisor does not depend on the ambient field (it is the same in any extension).

Comment: @Ayush Herstein's assertion is true in the context of the theorem (as Herstein proves in the two sentences following the claim). But it is not true generally.

Comment: @KeyIdeas- Herstein does not prove this. He just blankly states this, and moves on to something else.

Comment: @vonbrand- I'm convinced with your argument. But that implies a direct contradiction with Herstein's statement. I don't buy "sometimes this is true, sometimes it's not". If $b\notin \mathbb{F}$, then the minimal polynomial of $b$, whose degree is $\geq 2$, divides both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. This implies that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have more in common than just $(x-b)$ in $\mathbb{F[b,x]}$.

Comment: @Ayush : My take is a bit different.  Herstein considers, not the field $F,$ but the field $K=F(c)$ ($c$ defined earlier).  He never asserts that $b\notin K.$  On the contrary, he aims to prove that $b\in K,$ and he does this by showing that $x-b$ is the greatest common divisor of two polynomials in $K[x].$  From this it follows that $b\in K.$  So Herstein agrees with you.

Comment: @Ayush : Also, Herstein does prove that $x-b$ is the greatest common divisor of $g(x)$ and $h(x).$  This is done in the two sentences following "We assert that $x-b$ is their greatest common divisor."  He does this, in part, using $h(x)=f(c-\gamma x)$ and the definition of $\gamma.$

Comment: @WillOrrick- I thought about this, and came upon the exact same conclusion last night.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the only *linear* common factor of $p$ and $q$ is $x-b$. When? Since the minimum polynomial of $b$ divides $p$ and $q$, it must be of the form $(x-b)^k$, for some $k$.

This can actually happen: consider the field $K=\mathbb{F}_2(t)$ of rational functions over the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ with two elements. Then the polynomial $x^2-t\in K[x]$ is irreducible and it's the minimum polynomial over $K$ of its unique root.

On the contrary, if the field has characteristic $0$, this can't happen: an irreducible polynomial $f$ (like the minimum polynomial for $b$) has distinct roots, because $f$ and its derived polynomial cannot have common non constant factors.

Comment: We're talking about a field with $0$ characteristic. So the minimal polynomial can't have a multiple root.

Comment: @Ayush : it would be good to add that condition to the original post.

Comment: @WillOrrick- Done :)